# Return file path in jQuery file upload Blueimp(PHP)

Tags: php, jquery, forms, upload

I wanted a fancy upload bar for my website and felt [this one](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/)'s pretty cool
I have had different problems but finally managed to upload.

Question : How do I get the path of the uploaded file to insert in my database?

Answer (score 1):

In the function `handle_file_upload` in the `upload.class.php` file, after `$file_path`, I added:

```php
$url = 'YOUR PATH HERE/files/'.$file->name;
```

And then I included the `$url` var in my db insert. The `YOUR PATH HERE` would be whatever your structure is to get the `/server/php/files/` directory.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the file path as it is stored on the client machine (security issue).

You can get only the file name.

EDIT: Although some browsers (IE) *may* provide you with the path you cannot and should not rely on it.

Comment: I'm only interested in the file's path stored in server
its usually "server/php/files/filename"
How can I get the file name?
I tried the $_FILES array but to no avail

Comment: I am no PHP genius but by the looks of it you need to use `$HTTP_POST_FILES`: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php -- although `$_FILES` should also work (according to the link).  A comment there suggests this: "If $_FILES is always empty, check the method of your form.
It should be POST. Default method of a form is GET."